# Image galleries with possibilities to remove and rotate image using jquery

Tags: jquery, image, gallery

i need a jquery plugin that allows to show some image and give the possibilities to remove/rotate one or more image from gallery, like [in this site](https://annunci.ebay.it/pubblica-annuncio). Do you know any galleries that allows to do that? i know it is not a question that respect standard, but on web i don't find nothing similar.

Comment: in the example site i quoted, there is an input type file that allows to upload images. when one or more images are uploaded, it will show the preview of images ,like a gallery, with the possibilities to remove ( x upon image ) or rotate them

Comment: There is no plugin that does this.  You will more than likely have to code most of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved using [this jquery plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)